# RHEL 6: postmaster dead but pid file exists

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2 on RedHat 6

I'm a little confused as to why the following is happening:

1. When postgres is running, performing "service postgresql92-postgresql status" as root results in "postmaster (pid 1379) is running..." (as expected)
2. As postgres run "pg_ctl stop -D $PGDATA -m s" to stop postgres
3. As postgres run "pg_ctl -D $PGDATA start" to start postgres (postgres is now running correctly)
4. Now as root run "service postgresql92-postgresql status", output is now "postmaster dead but pid file exists"

My confusion is why am I getting the message in step 4 when postgres is running correctly? Am I stopping/starting postgres incorrectly?

Comment: If you don't do the step 3 (ie. start postgres), what does your step 4 outputs ?

Comment: the same "postmaster dead..." message, this message starts as soon as i use the "pg_ctl stop" command

Comment: Can you check the rights of your pid file ?

Comment: the postmaster.pid is 600 owned by postgres, there is also a postmaster.5432.pid which has 644 permissions and owned by root!

Comment: Can you cat the two pid files and check which one is used by `service postgresql92-postgresql status` ?

Comment: looks like the postmaster.pid is the one being used

Comment: Can you try to stop postgres, delete as root the two pid files and start postgres with the user postgres ?

Comment: ok, i stopped postgres, removed the pid files (the postmaster.pid was not there so i guess stopping postgres removed it). Started postgres again (as the postgres user). But, now even though postgres is running, a service postgresql92-postgresql status now shows "postmaster is stopped"

Comment: As postgres, can you test : `psql --version` ?

Comment: psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.10

Comment: Can you try to start postgres with `service postgresql92-postgresql start` as postgres user ?

Comment: Starting postgresql92-postgresql service: /etc/init.d/postgresql92-postgresql: line 124: echo: write error: Permission denied
touch: cannot touch `/opt/rh/postgresql92/root/var/lock/subsys/postgresql92-postgresql': Permission denied
/etc/init.d/postgresql92-postgresql: line 136: /opt/rh/postgresql92/root/var/run/postmaster.5432.pid: Permission denied

Comment: The `service postgresql92-postgresql start` is not checking the same pid file created by pg_ctl. I'm looking for the difference in order to elaborate an answer.
First workaround would be to check if postgres is launched with `ps aux`.

Comment: thanks for your efforts on this, i'm very new to postgres having spent years as an oracle dba. When performing a ps aux | grep postgres, i see lots of processing (logger, startup, checkpointer etc), there is also an " /opt/rh/postgresql92/root/usr/bin/postgres -D /vol2/postgres92/pgsql/data" service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`service postgresql92-postgresql status` checks if the file postmaster.5432.pid instead of postmaster.pid.

I'd recommend to use only `pg_ctl` as postgres and check with `ps aux` as root.
Or use only `service postgresql92-postgresql start/stop/status` as root. Mixing the two methods would turn into conflicts.